# NSRegularExpression NSInvalidValue Error 2048

Tags: objective-c, regex, cocoa

I am trying to use any of the regex expressions described in this post - [Regex/code for removing "FWD", "RE", etc, from email subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153629/regex-code-for-removing-fwd-re-etc-from-email-subject)

For example,

```
NSString *pattern = @"([\[\(] *)?(RE?S?|FYI|RIF|I|FS|VB|RV|ENC|ODP|PD|YNT|ILT|SV|VS|VL|AW|WG|ΑΠ|ΣΧΕΤ|ΠΡΘ|תגובה|הועבר|主题|转发|FWD?) *([-:;)\\]][ :;\\])-]*|$)|\\]+ *$";
NSError *error;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

NSRange textRange = NSMakeRange(0, workingSubject.length);
NSString *newSubject = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:workingSubject options:0 range:textRange withTemplate:@""];
```

but I always receive this error

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=2048 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 2048.)"
UserInfo=0x7fb6cde65530 {NSInvalidValue=([[(] *)?(RE?S?|FYI|RIF|I|FS|VB|RV|ENC|ODP|PD|YNT|ILT|SV|VS|VL|AW|WG|ΑΠ|ΣΧΕΤ|ΠΡΘ|תגובה|הועבר|主题|转发|FWD?) *([-:;)]][ :;])-]*|$)|\]+ *$}
```

What can I do to fix this?

For reference, I've also tried these expressions, with the same error:

```
 /([\[\(] *)?(RE|FWD?) *([-:;)\]][ :;\])-]*|$)|\]+ *$/igm

 ([\[\(] *)?(RE?S?|FYI|RIF|I|FS|VB|RV|ENC|ODP|PD|YNT|ILT|SV|VS|VL|AW|WG|ΑΠ|ΣΧΕΤ|ΠΡΘ|תגובה|הועבר|主题|转发|FWD?) *([-:;)\]][ :;\])-]*|$)|\]+ *$'

 /([\[\(] *)?(RE?S?|FYI|RIF|I|FS|VB|RV|ENC|ODP|PD|YNT|ILT|SV|VS|VL|AW|WG|ΑΠ|ΣΧΕΤ|ΠΡΘ|תגובה|הועבר|主题|转发|FWD?) *([-:;)\]][ :;\])-]*|$)|\]+ *$/im
```

Here are some examples of subjects that it should remove the leading modifiers (Re, Fw, Fwd, Aw, etc.) from, basically keeping "some subject...":

```
"Re: re: some subject asdf;'[]"
"Re: re: some subject asdf;'()"
"Re: re: some subject 12345678910"
"Re: re: some subject !@#$%^&*()_+`~"
"Re: re: some subject <>?:\"{},./;'[]|\\=-'"
"Re: re: some subject regarding"
"Fw: re: some subject regarding fwoo"
"Fw: FWD: some subject regarding fwoo"
"FWD: fw: some subject regarding fwoo"
"Fwd: RE: some subject regarding fwoo"
"Fwd: FWD: RE: re: some subject regarding fwoo"
"Aw: FWD: RE: re: some subject regarding fwoo"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is trying to escape the [ character

```
Incorrect: `NSString *pattern = @"([\[\(] *)?`  
Corrected: `NSString *pattern = @"([\\[(] *)?`  

Inside a character set only [ ] and \ need escaping.
Outside a character set only * ? + [ ( ) { } ^ $ | \ . need escaping.
```

You can split a RE (or any string) across lines and that can bring some clarity to a long re:

```
NSString *pattern = @
    "([\\[(] *)?" // leading [ or ( followed by optional spaces zero or one times
    "(RE?S?|FYI|RIF|I|FS|VB|RV|ENC|ODP|PD|YNT|ILT|SV|VS|VL|AW|WG|ΑΠ|ΣΧΕΤ|ΠΡΘ|תגובה|הועבר|主题|转发|FWD?) *"
    "([-:;)\\]][ :;\\])-]*|$)"
        "|"
    "\\]+ *$";
```

I ran the RE against the examples:

```
NSArray *subjectList = @[
     @"Re: re: some subject asdf;'[]",
     @"Re: re: some subject asdf;'()",
     @"Re: re: some subject 12345678910",
     @"Re: re: some subject !@#$%^&*()_+`~",
     @"Re: re: some subject <>?:\"{},./;'[]|\\=-'",
     @"Re: re: some subject regarding",
     @"Fw: re: some subject regarding fwoo",
     @"Fw: FWD: some subject regarding fwoo",
     @"FWD: fw: some subject regarding fwoo",
     @"Fwd: RE: some subject regarding fwoo",
     @"Fwd: FWD: RE: re: some subject regarding fwoo",
     @"Aw: FWD: RE: re: some subject regarding fwoo"
     ];

NSString *pattern = @
"([\\[(] *)?" // leading [ or ( followed by optional spaces zero or one times
"(RE?S?|FYI|RIF|I|FS|VB|RV|ENC|ODP|PD|YNT|ILT|SV|VS|VL|AW|WG|ΑΠ|ΣΧΕΤ|ΠΡΘ|תגובה|הועבר|主题|转发|FWD?) *"
"([-:;)\\]][ :;\\])-]*|$)"
"|"
"\\]+ *$";

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
for (NSString *subject in subjectList) {
    NSRange   subjectRange = NSMakeRange(0, subject.length);
    NSString *newSubject = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:subject options:0 range:subjectRange withTemplate:@""];
    NSLog(@"newSubject: %@", newSubject);
}
```

Output:

```
newSubject: some subject asdf;'[
newSubject: some subject asdf;'()
newSubject: some subject 12345678910
newSubject: some subject !@#$%^&*()_+`~
newSubject: some subject ?:"{},./;'[]|\=-'
newSubject: some subject regarding
newSubject: some subject regarding fwoo
newSubject: some subject regarding fwoo
newSubject: some subject regarding fwoo
newSubject: some subject regarding fwoo
newSubject: some subject regarding fwoo
newSubject: some subject regarding fwoo
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixes the error, although the regex needs some changes to correctly accomplish what I'd like to do, which is stripping leading email subject modifiers such as "Re", "Fw", etc.

Comment: If this is still not working for you can you explain the incorrect result and provide some examples that are failing along with the desired results?

Comment: I ended up using the following pattern, the right to left replacement does not work correctly:
     NSString *pattern = @"([\\[\(] *)?(RE?S?|FYI|RIF|I|FS|VB|RV|ENC|ODP|PD|YNT|ILT|SV|VS|VL|AW|WG|ΑΠ|ΣΧΕΤ|ΠΡΘ|主题|转发|FWD?) *([-:;)\\]][ :;\\])-]*|$)|\\]+ *$";

Comment: Thanks for your help in finding the '[' escape bug!